# Copy value of field with button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple button using jquery. When the user clicks a button, the value of 'timestart' is copied into 'timeend'.

```
<input id="timestart" name="timestart" value="" /> 
<!-- need button here: Click here to copy/paste value into timeend field -->
<input id="timeend" name="timeend" value="" />
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<input id="timestart" name="timestart" value="" />
<button id='copy'>Copy</button>
<input id="timeend" name="timeend" value="" />
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#copy").on("click",function(){
      $("#timeend").val($("#timestart").val())   
    })
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CQJtR/)**

Comment: Still trying to work with jquery as a newbie. Thanks for all the quick replies. Great responses and solutions. This solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Put a button in there, give it an ID or some other defining characteristic, and simply set the value of `timeend` when it's clicked. This example assumes some element with an ID of "yourButton":

```
$("#yourButton").on("click", function () {
    $("#timeend").val($("#timestart").val());
});
```

References:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

This is very simple stuff. I would suggest spending some time reading through the jQuery docs to get an idea of the methods available to you.

Answer (score 2):

do it like this

```
 $('#btnSubmit')​.click(function(){
        $('#timeend').val($('#timestart').val());
    });
```

​[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F5Ehg/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    var val = $('#timestart').val();
    $('input#timeend').val(val);
});
```